# simple_list_item_multiple_choice No guarda los elementos marcados

Tags: android, lista, android-listview

Supuestamente con el metodo getCheckedItemPositions se pueden obtener los elementos marcaddos, sin embargo siempre me devuelve un array vacio.... Marcar se marcan automaticamente de forma correcta (inluso incluido en el codigo que se seteara el elemento como marcado) pero parece que la informacion no la esta guardando. Dejo el trozo de codigo más abajo:

```
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listaElementos));
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                CheckedTextView texto = (CheckedTextView) view;
                if (texto.isChecked()) {
                    view.setSelected(true);
                    listaElementosFiltro.add(texto.getText().toString());
                } else {
                    listaElementosFiltro.remove(texto.getText());
                }
            }
        });


SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
```